# C# write to json file with SimpleJSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, read-write, simplejson

SimpleJSON link https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON

There is no documentation and I am trying to understand how to (add/delete/edit) information into the JSON file below.

- All Values are strings
- I want to know how to Add JSON Object/Array like shown below to the file
- Delete a whole object/array ex:("Character0":{...})
- edit a Node x["Character0"]["Head"].Value = "New Head" so that value updates

*Any help would be awesome if you know how the SimpleJson class works would be helpful.*

**JSON FILE**

```
{
"Character0":{
    "Head":"HeadCube",
    "Neck":"NeckCube",
    "Body":"BodyCube",
    "Arms":"Sphere_Capsule_Arms",
    "Legs":"Sphere_Capsule_Legs"
    }
}
```

Comment: Json.net is available for unity3d. Is there any reason you would choose a undocumented library over it? Not to mentioned, you are more likely to run into some bug with that.

Comment: JSON Utility is also available. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html